# Making games in iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Can anyone tell me what should i use to make games for iPhone...

Actually i am a simple application programmer ...but never made complicated high graphics games...
i have made some games but only simple one...
Which tool is good for me to start....
i am aware of OPenGL...is it good to start with this ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say if you're reasonably competent with iOS & Objective-C, then it might be worth taking a peek at the likes of Cocos2D.  There's also the iOS port of Flixel (which you can grab with the source to Canabalt which is sitting on Github), but compared to Cocos2D - it's a little less polished due to it only being recently out there.

Unity's great if you're familiar with C# or JavaScript and interested in wanting to do 3D games - and if you're not as interested in going the full-hog with learning OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 2):

[Corona](http://www.anscamobile.com/) is the best thing for you start looking into.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a trip to the bookstore, to find a book which speaks to you, regarding iPhone Game Dev. A quick look at Amazon reveals quite a number.

There's a lot to consider when making games, it's a huge topic.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Unity 3D](http://unity3d.com/).

Answer (score 1):

For someone new to iPhone development and game dev in general, I'd say start with Cocoa Touch as it is simpler than OpenGL and you can create simple games (for example words games) with it. And even if you decide to develop an OpenGL app for the iOs you still need to work with Cocoa so there is no escape from learning it.

Once you get your head around objective-c/cocoa/xcode and iphone development in general, then start looking at OpenGL.